# Will there be a second season of RWBY?

Tags: rwby

I was wondering when the season 2 of RWBY would be released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick google search reveals that

> RWBY Vol 2 will premeire at RTX July 4-6 this year! Thank you all for your support and contributions. [source](https://twitter.com/montyoum/status/428969903883030528)